# How to calculate YTW (yield-to-worst) in QuantLib?

Tags: python, quantlib, bond-yields

After defining a CallableFixedRateBond object in QuantLib, I can calculate YTM (yield-to-maturity) right now. I'm using Python so the function is bondYield().

Is there any way to calculate YTW (yield-to-worst) in QuantLib? One way is to loop through all callable dates and calculate yield assuming the bond will be called at exact that date. Then take minimum of them. Is there a more straightforward way to do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely about programming (without providing a MCV example) and not about Quantitative Finance.

Comment: I think it's fine, I read it as asking for guidance on how to approach this problem  within the context of QuantLib, not for programming help.

Comment: Maybe the question could be restated without being library specific. E.g. if you consider a long-dated bond, say 30 years, with complicated call schedule, say anyime (American) on or after 5 years, with changing strikes (say par + all remaining coupons).  Do you need to calculate the yield for each possible call date to find the worst, or is there a shortcut?